# How can I submit a value to this javascript using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I submit a value to this javascript function using javascript. Here is the code:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">      

   function myFunction(){

        var x=document.getElementById("demo").value;

   }

   </script>
```

Basically I want to change having the get value by id and instead get the value by javascript so something like this code. Here is the code:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">

        var x = "1";

   </script>
```

How can I submit my value to my javascript using javascript?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking - instead of getting value from HTML field you want to hardcode it? If so why not just replace one code with another

Comment: Check your previously asked question there you got answers. Do not put same question again and again. @BlackSheep has posted your previously asked question's link

Comment: I want to hardcode it in javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this:

```
function myFunction(y){

    var x=y;

    //do something else with x

}

$('button').on('click',function() {

    var val = $(this).val();

    //x in myFunction is now val
    myFunction(val);

});
```

Comment: But how can I submit the value?

Comment: You mean, with an html form?

Comment: Like "myFunction();" in <script>

Comment: AHHHHHHHHHHHHH Got it window.onload

Answer (score 0):

The question isn't very clear, but maybe:

```
function myFunction(x) {
    // Do stuff with x
}

var y = document.getElementById("demo").value;
myFunction(y);
```